# Problem using jupyterhub-tmpauthenticator

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dockerfile, jupyterhub

Getting below error when I try using this authenticator on docker

```
500 : Internal Server Error

Error in Authenticator.pre_spawn_start: FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'systemctl'

You can try restarting your server from the home page.
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM jupyter/minimal-notebook:latest
RUN pip install notebook jupyterhub-tmpauthenticator jupyterhub-systemdspawner
COPY jupyterhub_config.py  /home/jovyan/jupyterhub_config.py
```

jupyterhub_config.py

```py
import tmpauthenticator
import systemdspawner
c=get_config()
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class=tmpauthenticator.TmpAuthenticator
c.JupyterHub.spawner_class=systemdspawner.SystemdSpawner
c.SystemdSpawner.dynamic_users=True
```

Comment: Will be good If I get a working dockerfile or image with the above requirements. I have been struggling with this for the past one week